# GDAL WMS in QGIS 2.4

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, wms

I'm trying to add in QGIS a layer shown here : [propluvia](http://propluvia.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/propluvia/faces/public/carteDep.jsp)

When I watch in my console I see [this request](http://eau.agriculture.gouv.fr/WMS-T.php?map=/export/home/rimboval/geomap/mapfiles/propluvia.map&LAYERS=Zones_Niveau_Sup&DATE=2014-08-18&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A2154&BBOX=508204,6363402.704938,627904.88806,6468402.704938&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256) corresponding to the layer I need.

The server is not able to respond to a getCapabilities request for whatever reason.

So I tried to load this layer via this GDAL XML file.

```
<GDAL_WMS>
<Service name="WMS">
    <ServerUrl>http://eau.agriculture.gouv.fr/WMS-T.php?map=/export/home/rimboval/geomap/mapfiles/propluvia.map&</ServerUrl>
    <SRS>EPSG:2154</SRS>
    <ImageFormat>image/png</ImageFormat>
    <Transparent>TRUE</Transparent>
    <Layers>Zones_Niveau_Sup</Layers>
    <Change key="${date}">2014-08-18</Change>
</Service>
<DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>508204</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>6363402</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>627904</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>6468402</LowerRightY>
    <SizeX>256</SizeX>
    <SizeY>256</SizeY>
</DataWindow>
```

I'm using key="${date}" because I saw it [here](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_twms_daily.xml).

The resulting image looks like in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81114/gdal-tms-wms-mini-driver).

[image: noisy image]

I tried to watch what QGIS is requesting with fiddler but I can't see any request while it is working with a valid WMS layer.

Comment: You have <UpperLeftY>6363402 and  <LowerRightY>6468402. I would try to use bigger number as upper coordinate.

Comment: You're right. I had to reverse this values but the result is the same.