# How to use QGIS tile server provider with local TMS folder

Tags: qgis, tile-map-service

I just learned that QGIS 2.18 has a *Tile Server (XYZ)* provider in the Browser Panel. I created a large tile map using gdal2tiles and I'm trying to load it. However, I'm **not** publishing the tiles through a web server instead, I though about reading the files strait from the disk. So, in the Tile Server url I used `file:///I:/SUL/rapid_tms_utm21/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`. The tiles do not load and I see the following error in the log panel: `Tile request max retry error. Failed 3 requests for tile 13 of tileRequest 2 (url: file:///I/SUL/rapid_tms_utm21/6/19/38.png)`.

So, the questions are:

1. Does QGIS Tile Server provider works with local files?
2. Can I use the `file:///` protocol? How?

I tried the following lines as the TMS Server address:

- file:///I:/SUL/rapid_tms_utm21/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
- file:///I/SUL/rapid_tms_utm21/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
- I:/SUL/rapid_tms_utm21/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
- I/SUL/rapid_tms_utm21/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
- /I/SUL/rapid_tms_utm21/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
- /I:/SUL/rapid_tms_utm21/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
- file://I:/SUL/rapid_tms_utm21/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
- file://I/SUL/rapid_tms_utm21/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

And the tiles work using the TileLayerPlugin

Comment: It does not works for me with `file:///F:/Tiles/Topo/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`, but using the WM(t)S.xml file it does.

Comment: ... and works with a local Apache server from ms4w, targetting to the tiles root folder.

Comment: @AndreJ So if I correctly create the GetCapabilties.xml file and place it in the top level of the tile files hierarchy, QGIS will correctly access those tiles off disk as if they were being served by an actual tile server application?

Comment: @Joebocop you can try on your own, I had no success without an Apache server. The TileLayerPlugin works for me without the Apache server (unless you zoom in and out heavily https://github.com/minorua/TileLayerPlugin/issues/29 ), but I don't know if it will be continued in QGIS 3.

Comment: See issue [#35](https://github.com/minorua/TileLayerPlugin/issues/35?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container) on GitHub. Unfortunately, TileLayer (and hence the seamless integration of local `{z}/{x}/{y}` tiles) is currently not on schedule for QGIS 3.

Comment: Solution is explained [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326125/open-google-earth-cache-file-in-qgis-3/326132#326132](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326125/open-google-earth-cache-file-in-qgis-3/326132#326132)

Comment: @AndreJ How did you configure with local apache and target local folder.  Please explain in details.

Comment: @Sachin see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

For use of a local Apache Server from the ms4w package, I installed MS4w into `C:\ms4w\` and stored the tiles folder structure beneath `C:\Tiles\`.

Then I edited the file `C:\ms4w\Apache\conf` around line 252 to change the DocumentRoot to:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Tiles"
<Directory "C:/Tiles">
```

Tiles can then be accessed by something like `http://localhost/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`

This is rather a dirty hack, but works for me.

Answer (score 1):

@daniel You need to specify the tiles path exactly as follow :

`file:///I://SUL//rapid_tms_utm21//sat//{z}//{x}//{y}.png` **<--**

This is working for QGIS 3 as well.

Comment: The path of my drive is like "D:\sasplanet\cache\sat\z7\0\x28\0\y24.jpg" and I added the path in XYZ connection as "file:///D://sasplanet//cache//sat//z{z}//{x}//{y}.jpg" but noting displays.

Comment: You need to edit  **SAS.PLANET Configuration** :

| **1** : `Click on Settings>Options>`  

| **2** : `Default cache type : GlobalMapper Tiles`  
  
| **3** : `GlobalMapper Tiles (GMT) cache folder: cache_gmt  `

Good Luck

Comment: refer to my answer here for more detail : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326125/using-open-google-earth-cache-file-in-qgis/326132#326132

Comment: then @sachin-kumar  use path in XYZ connection as  `file:///D://Software//SAS.Planet//cache_gmt//sat//z{z}//{y}//{x}.jpg`

Comment: QGIS 3.32. Don't work