# Loading tiles from local TMS using XYZ Tiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, tile-map-service, tile-server, xyz-tiles

I have exported the map tiles with the Raster tool box, and saved the tiles in the QGIS default temp folder with 512x512 resolution and 96 dpi.

[image]

Now I'm trying to load the tiles back to QGIS. After some reading, looks like XYZ Tiles is the best way to go. However, after loading, the map images do not show up in QGIS.

[image]

The URL that I entered was:

```
file:////var/folders/j8/_8nfnqv119n7_wswhm_5bhwr0000gn/T/processing_501b13906436489496768b2c01c2497a/c5bcb3f8e6be499bb887621a56ea2ce3/OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

I also tried the following according to the answer in this post [How to use QGIS tile server provider with local TMS folder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219118/how-to-use-qgis-tile-server-provider-with-local-tms-folder). But both of them do not work.

```
file:////var//folders//j8//_8nfnqv119n7_wswhm_5bhwr0000gn//T//processing_501b13906436489496768b2c01c2497a//c5bcb3f8e6be499bb887621a56ea2ce3//OUTPUT_DIRECTORY//{z}//{x}//{y}.png
```

My QGIS version is 3.10.10, and I use MacOS.

Answer (score 2):

I just found the solution. I should set the min zoom level and max zoom level to be the same as the export setting.

[image]

Comment: Please mark your answer as solution for the question. :)