# Displaying/opening local TMS with QGIS

Tags: qgis, tile-map-service

I want to display the content of a local TMS (a tile map, stored in a directory structure `Z/X/Y.png`) in QGIS.

This is for quick check and comparison.
I am not willing to set WMTS webserver for this purpose.

I tried to load this kind of file in QGIS but I got only a white or stripped map

```
  <GDAL_WMS>
  <Service name="TMS">
    <ServerUrl>file:///vdata/myTMS/${z}/${x}/${y}.png</ServerUrl>
     <Format>png</Format>
     <Transparent>TRUE</Transparent>
  </Service>
  <DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY>
    <TileLevel>11</TileLevel>
    <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
    <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
    <YOrigin>bottom</YOrigin>
  </DataWindow>
  <Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
  <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
  <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
   <BandsCount>4</BandsCount>   
 </GDAL_WMS>
```

*I am running QGIS 2.14*

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219035/open-local-tms-in-qgis-using-gdal

Comment: Based on answers above the easiest way to get it running might be with the [TileLayer](https://github.com/minorua/TileLayerPlugin/) plugin.

Comment: ... unless you intend to use QGIS3: https://github.com/minorua/TileLayerPlugin/issues/35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works directly at least in QGIS 3.6+ (likely some previous versions as well):

- In the content browser, right-click on "XYZ Tiles" and select "New connection..."
- Specify a name and for the URL, use `file:///$PATH/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` which points to your local tiles

Hope this helps -- Alex

Comment: Tested with [Maperitive](http://maperitive.net/) generated tiles in QGIS 3.16.0, works like a charm!