# QGIS, Tilemap stored in local folder or in project directory

Tags: qgis

I created an offline tilemap and want to use it as background map in QGIS. I like to store the maptiles in the project folder. The QGIS-Project should work independently from any installation or plugin.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: It seems the only way to load local tiles was through the tilelayerplugin, which hasn't been updated for QGIS 3.0. Check out these similar questions: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219118/how-to-use-qgis-tile-server-provider-with-local-tms-folder https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280408/how-to-simply-display-open-a-local-tile-map-tms-with-qgis https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219035/open-local-tms-in-qgis-using-gdal

Comment: The tilelayerplugin is the best solution I found so far. But I didn't find out how to setup a relative path for the tilefolder.

Comment: I think that the VectorTilesPlugin could be helpful, but actually I don't know how to produce the vector tiles.